# Why adding a subView to UIButton, from a custom UIView doesn't show the added subViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, subclass

I have a subclass of UIView, that I'm loading from a NIB file. My NIB file, contains a UIButton and an IBOutlet to it, called **clock**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clock;
```

The text set in my clock button, on my interface builder, shows up! But everother subview that I add from initWithCoder doesn't. Why is this?

**.h file**

```
@interface TWTimerView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clock;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *circle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *pointer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *tick;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *circleGlow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *pointerGlow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *tickGlow;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation TWTimerView

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        _circle  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"]];
        _pointer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pointer"]];
        _tick    = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"]];

        [_clock addSubview:_circle];
        [_clock addSubview:_pointer];
        [_clock addSubview:_tick];

    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        TWTimerView *view= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:view];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you adding imageviews to uibutton???

Comment: Yes, my UIButton is my _clock. I'm adding them like this: [_clock addSubview:_image];

Comment: Are you actually adding a `TWTimerView` as a subview of a `TWTimerView` when calling `initWithFrame` ? Or is TimerView just a regular .xib file with some kind of content subview ?

Comment: you should set a frame to your UIImageViews..

Comment: also setting the alpha channel to 0.0 makes that object completely transparent, as in you wouldn't see it on the screen

Comment: @Nerkatel TWTimerView is loaded from a .xib file, yes! I'm loading the .xib file and adding it as a subview of self (my TWTimerView).

Comment: @codeInOrange the first 3 images are not transparent. I've removed the other 3 from the question, so not to confuse.

Comment: @JulienKlindt my UIImages frame is being correctly set from initWithImage. It's set to the Image's size. I can confirm this from my object's description.

Comment: I don't get why you would want to allocate twice your view though... Are you sure the `initWithCoder` method is called ?

Comment: According to my test it is not, do you really need to use the `initWithFrame` method or can i define another method to load the view for you ?

Comment: @Nerkatel yes, yes it is. I just checked. When you say 2 times, should I not be using initWithFrame to load my nib?

Comment: Accepted an answer, thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do :
If you dont need to use the frame, drop the `initWithFrame` method and use another method to help you load the view, like this.

```
+ (id)loadViewFromNIBFile {
    NSArray * array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerView" owner:self options:nil];
    //You may want to assert array only contains one element here
    TWTimerView * view = (TWTimerView *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSAssert([view isKindOfClass:TWTimerView.class], @"Unexpected class");
    [view _setDefaultComponents];
    return view;
}

- (void)_setDefaultComponents {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _circle  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"]];
    _pointer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pointer"]];
    _tick    = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"]];
    [_clock addSubview:_circle];
    [_clock addSubview:_pointer];
    [_clock addSubview:_tick];
}
```

Call `[TWTimerView loadViewFromNIBFile]` to get a instance of your view.

Answer (score 0):

Your TWTimerView has a nib, in which you have a UIButton? And you have an UIView-Subclass, that is adding three UIImageViews to your UIButton, why you do this?!

Why not subclass the UIButton and set the UIImageViews there?

At all i would change it to this:

```
@implementation TWTimerView

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
            [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            _circle  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"]];
            _pointer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pointer"]];
            _tick    = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"]];

            [_clock addSubview:_circle];
            [_clock addSubview:_pointer];
            [_clock addSubview:_tick];

        }
        return self;
    }

@end
```

Comment: TWTimerView is a subclass of UIView. This subclass initializes from a NIB file. This nib file has a UIButton. I could subclass UIButton yes, nevertheless, this should be working. Just tried to set up my UIImageViews in my UIButton, as you suggestes, from initWithFrame. No luck so far.